# How use Runnable with mockito in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, runnable

I using JUNIT and Mockito with Spring Boot and Java 8, Whats the correct way fo execute a unit test using Runnable? When apply a simple test and execute, It is not cover the 3th line.

```
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("taskExecutor")
  private Executor executor;

    public void publishMsgs(List<Message> msgs) {
    for (Message message : msgs) {
      Runnable sendMessageAsync = () -> sendMsg(message);//THIS LINE IS NOT COVERAGE 
      CompletableFuture.runAsync(sendMessageAsync, executor);
    }
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: _Most likely_ it's because you aren't joining the future (that is, the test finishes before the async execution does).

Comment: Please show your test in your question as well.